# Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined when using React-Sparklines

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using the third party component react-sparklines for a project. However, when I import it to my component as shown below it throws the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined**. But when I take it out, the error goes away and the app runs smoothly.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { Sparklines, SparklinesLine } from 'react-sparklines';

class WeatherList extends React.Component{
  renderCity(cityData){
    const name = cityData.city.name;
    const temps = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp);

    return (
      <tr key={name}>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>
<Sparklines data={[5, 10, 5, 20]}>
  <SparklinesLine color="blue" />
</Sparklines>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return { weather: state.weather };}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```

Please note I knowingly left out the `render()` function. Here's the link to Sparklines: https://github.com/borisyankov/react-sparklines

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Version 1.7.0 of Sparklines has a bug. Consider downgrading to a lower version, in this case version 1.6.0:

```
npm r react-sparklines
npm i --save react-sparklines@1.6.0
```

You might want to get more information here: https://github.com/borisyankov/react-sparklines/issues/89

Comment: This did it for me! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -3):

you need to define constructor in your class.

```js
constructor(props){
  super(props);
}
```

Comment: No you don't in this case.